# Filter by bounding box in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, overlapping-features, extents

I have a GeoPandas DataFrame in EPSG:4326 and I'd make a new DataFrame consisting of all the rows that fall within a certain bounding box.

First I get the bounding box that I care about (which is actually the bounding box of another DataFrame):

```py
print(df_sussex.total_bounds)
[ -1.57239292  50.57467674   0.14528384  51.27465152]
```

Then I make a DataFrame consisting only of that bounding box:

```py
pts = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_sussex.total_bounds)
```

And finally, I try to get all the features that intersect with that bounding box:

```py
sac_sussex = gpd.overlay(pts, df_sac, how='intersection')
```

But this gives me:

> AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column
> 'geometry'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Issue is because you are using 'total_bounds' method. It only produces a tuple with max and min points of bounding box. Method to be used is 'envelope'; previous to build its respective **GeoDataFrame**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issue is because you are using 'total_bounds' method. It only produces a tuple with max and min points of bounding box. Method to be used is 'envelope'; previous to build its respective 'GeoDataFrame'. For instance, reading my shapefiles as **GeoDataFrame**:

```
import geopandas as gpd
pol1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("pyqgis_data/polygon1.shp")
pol8 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp")
```

Building bounding box of **pol1** and creating its respective **GeoDataFrame**:

```
bounding_box = pol1.envelope
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries(bounding_box), columns=['geometry'])
```

Intersecting both **GeoDataFrame**:

```
intersections = gpd.overlay(df, pol8, how='intersection')
```

Plotting results:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
intersections.plot()
```

[image]

It worked as expected.

**Editing Note:**

By using 'total_bounds' method (because 'envelope' method returns the bounding box for each feature of polygons), it can be used this approach:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

pol1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("pyqgis_data/polygon1.shp")
pol8 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp")

bbox = pol1.total_bounds

p1 = Point(bbox[0], bbox[3])
p2 = Point(bbox[2], bbox[3])
p3 = Point(bbox[2], bbox[1])
p4 = Point(bbox[0], bbox[1])

np1 = (p1.coords.xy[0][0], p1.coords.xy[1][0])
np2 = (p2.coords.xy[0][0], p2.coords.xy[1][0])
np3 = (p3.coords.xy[0][0], p3.coords.xy[1][0])
np4 = (p4.coords.xy[0][0], p4.coords.xy[1][0])

bb_polygon = Polygon([np1, np2, np3, np4])

df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries(bb_polygon), columns=['geometry'])

intersections2 = gpd.overlay(df2, pol8, how='intersection')

plt.ion()
intersections2.plot()
```

and result is identical.

Answer (score 47):

You can use the `cx` method on a geodataframe to select rows within a bounding box. For your example frames:

```
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = df_sussex.total_bounds
sac_sussex = df_sac.cx[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
```

From http://geopandas.org/indexing.html:

> In addition to the standard pandas methods, GeoPandas also provides coordinate based indexing with the **cx** indexer, which slices using a bounding box. Geometries in the GeoSeries or GeoDataFrame that intersect the bounding box will be returned.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thank you. However, I was wondering if there's a faster way to implement. Filtering OSM land-use and places that fall within a province's bounding box.

Comment: Note that `.cx` does something slightly different than the `gpd.overlay` solution: it selects rows that intersect the bounding box but leaves the geometries intact, whereas the `gpd.overlay` solution will only return the parts of the geometries in the bounding box. Depending on the situation you may want one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution to this if the shape you want to clip by is a box:

```py
from shapely.geometry import box

bbox = box(*df_sussex.total_bounds)
df_clipped = gpd.mask(df, mask=bbox)
```

It uses the [`shapely.geometry.box()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.box) function.

Comment: `gpd.mask()` isn't a GeoPandas function, perhaps this should read `df_clipped = gpd.clip(df, mask=bbox)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you want to use a buffer on the bounding box.

```
def filter_by_overlay_and_bounding_box(from_shape, filter, buffer_dist=0):
"""
Given a input shape (from_shape), a filter gdb and a buffer dist, this function returns
geometry from 'from_shape' which lies within the bounds on the filter shape + buffer
Args:
    from_shape (): 
    filter ():
    buffer_dist ():

Returns:

"""
    import shapely
    bound = shapely.geometry.box(*filter.total_bounds).buffer(buffer_dist)
    bound = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries(bound), columns=['geometry'])
    bound = bound.set_crs(from_shape.crs)
    return gpd.overlay(from_shape, bound, how='intersection')
```