# Any Python modules with an equivalent to ArcGIS Pro "Average Nearest Neighbour Distance" tool?

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor

ArcGIS Pro offers the `Average Nearest Neighbour Distance` geoprocessing tool to measure the distance between each feature centroid and its nearest neighbour's centroid location. It then averages all these nearest neighbour distances and provides a report of: Observed Mean Distance, Expected Mean Distance, Nearest Neighbour Index, z-score, and p-value

For more information on how the tool works see below:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/h-how-average-nearest-neighbor-distance-spatial-st.htm

I'm curious as to whether any Python modules offer similar functionality? I'd like to be able to incorporate some kind of nearest neighbour analysis in future scripts - in particular, observed mean distance and expected mean distance.

Comment: It's a script tool, why not right click on and choose edit, then you can see exactly how ESRI are doing it and what python modules they are using.

Comment: @Hornbydd the tool uses ```arcpy```

Comment: Look at the answer of  Taras in   [Looking for Python equivalent of QGIS "Nearest Neighbour analysis" tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/430041/2581)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with networkx. First the data should be converted into networkx graph nodes and edges using python code.
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html
Then use the inbuilt methods of networkx to find distance, nearest neighbour etc.
https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.assortativity.k_nearest_neighbors.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a tool like this. Have a look at https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisnearestneighbouranalysis

Comment: Thanks but I'd like a python way of doing it. In order to execute the above tool I'd have to run ```qgis.core``` and that is not ideal in my case

Comment: Then add this information (not being able to use qgis.core) to your question